# How to remove padding and margin from bootstrap columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove padding and margin from bootstrap columns for thati added noPadding class mentioned in question, but its not removing margin and padding from between col-md-3 and col-md-6 on submit button its working, Any idea ?

main.html

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <form role="form">
        <!--<div class="form-group">-->
        <div class="col-md-3 nopaddingPanel">
            <label>Search Server</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 nopaddingPanel">
            <!-- <form name="searchForm" class="form" ng-submit="submit()"> -->
            <div ng-class="{ 'has-error': searchForm.searchName.$invalid || searchForm.searchId.$invalid }">
                <input name="searchName" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.search" type="text" id="searchName" placeholder="Search" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="searchServerFile()">Search</button>
        </div>
        <!-- </form> -->
        <!--</div>-->
    </form>
</div>
```

main.css

```
.nopaddingPanel {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a CSS selector that is [more specific](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) than bootstrap's, then you can just use `padding: 0` or [`padding: unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset).

Avoid using `!important` whenever possible. It creates far more headaches than it solves. See [When Using Important is the Right Choice](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

For example, the following should work:

```css
.col-md-3.nopaddingPanel {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Notice that this selector is more specific... it uses two class names rather than one, which means it will win over bootstrap's (which uses just one class name in its selector).

Comment: Avoid using `unset` as it's not very well supported, mainly due to IE.

Comment: @DanielJames - good to know.

Comment: so what i should use instead of !important if i dont want to overwrite bootstrap class ?

Comment: @hussain A more specific CSS selector... when two CSS styles conflict, the more specific selector wins. It's all a little complicated, which is why I provided the link, but basically you just need to provide more class names than the bootstrap stylesheet.

Comment: @hussain Updated with example.

Comment: still did not work i applied to .col-md-6.nopaddingPanel

Comment: @hussain Then I suspect there is another issue. Use your browser's developer tools to make sure that your CSS file is loading, and that your HTML is what you expect it to be.